# Is it safe to use TOR on windows?

Tags: windows, networking, security, tor

I mean, can I be hacked just by browsing regular sites (not the hidden services) with TOR browser bundle running on a Windows system?

Comment: You can only be "hacked" if there is a exploitable vulnerability that exists on your system.  Even if a vulnerability exist it might be useless.  Your question is extremely broad.

Comment: TOR has nothing to do with whether or not you can or might get "hacked". By the time you reach the remote site, the only way they can know that tor was used at all is that your IP address is that of an exit node, which provides them no additional capability to interact with the software running on your PC than they would have it you connected to them without using TOR.  The only possible exception to this are NSA systems attempting to de-anonomize TOR usage (something they had only minimal success with), but once again, if you connected without tor, they could id you as easily.

Answer (score 1):

Using TOR does not change the ability for you to get hacked by visiting a infected website.

The only thing TOR provides is the ability for a website not to know where a connection is established from. It has nothing to do with preventing you from downloading malicious code.